# Linux wifi hardware that supports many managed interfaces

Tags: linux, wifi, network-interface, hardware, iw

I need to aquire hardware (can be a wifi card or a router) that is capable of simulating many wifi stations on one wifi radio.

Something similar to this (from arch linux wiki):

```
$ iw list

Wiphy phy1
...
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
...
```

I have discovered that i need a SoftMac device, possibly with ath9k driver, however i have not been able to find specifications for any hardware that supports this.
Ideally it needs to support 20+ stations. Any recomendations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic here

Comment: I understand your concern, im not looking for shopping recommendations per-se, I just want to know where can I check these sort of specifications without having the hardware

Comment: If you just need to **simulate** stations, and they don't need to be present on physical Wifi, you can also use `mac80211_hwsim` (which sets up a "virtual" internal WLAN network, with as many APs and STAs as you want). I also think finding a single Wifi card with 20+ stations capability will be quite difficult.

Comment: yes I am aware of mac80211_hwsim but I need physical stations